# Userdefault value comparison with textfield

Tags: ios, swift

i am trying to compare in login form  password value with UserDefault value . but an error occur that bool operation cant be perform there.
Please can any one help me compare both values.
How can i compare these values?

Comment: Please, can you add your code and the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, show your tried code so we can help you, Past your code.

Comment: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'String?'

Comment: That is because the return type of `object(forKey:)` is of type `Any?`, so you would have to cast it to proper type and them compare

Answer (score 2):

```
if let savedPassword = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password") {

    let enteredPassword = textField?.text

    if savedPassword == enteredPassword {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
else {
    // Failure.
}
```

I wouldn't recommend storing passwords in plain text in UserDefaults.

There are a number of tutorials on this topic available, for example https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/securing-user-data-with-keychain-for-ios-e720e0f9a8e2

Comment: Good point - wasn't thinking when I wrote this earlier! Will update.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code snippet

```
if passwordField.text == UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:"password"){
  print("Same Password")
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is wrong. You have to specify the type . UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"password") returns Any

Comment: Please use **always** dedicated `string(forKey` method and **never** `value(forKey` even for other ***objects***.

Comment: You're not comparing anything here, your just assigning value of password to textField.text, but this will produce error cannot assign value of Any? to String?

Comment: i am not assigning value but i am comparing values due to double == sign

Comment: will you please implement your that step in code form i cant understand yet but answer seems right

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify your object type

```
if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "password") == passwordLabel.text {
    // ...
    }
```

Comment: Please use **always** dedicated `string(forKey` method and `object(forKey` cannot be casted to `Bool` anyway.

Comment: If I want a Bool Object ? I think "string(forKey" doen not return bool type.

Comment: `object(forKey` doesn't either. In terms of `UserDefaults` `Bool` is **not** an object. For `Bool` there is `bool(forKey` but that's not the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should cast your result from Any to String from User Defaults

```
if let yourString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "yourString"), yourString == passwordTextField.text {
   // do something here
}
```

Comment: Please use **always** dedicated `string(forKey` method.

Comment: Now remove also `as? String`. That's the benefit of using specific API 

Comment: Yeap, thanx for helping